# Define class in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to define the following class but it's giving me an error:

**Error: declare dashboardFloatingPane: mixin #0 is not a callable constructor.**

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dnd/move", "dojox/layout/FloatingPane"],
  function(declare, move, FloatingPane){
    return declare("dashboardFloatingPane", [move, FloatingPane], {

    constructor: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.moveable = new dojo.dnd.move.constrainedMoveable(
                this.domNode, {
                    handle: this.focusNode,
                    constraints: function() {
                        var coordsWindow = {
                            l: 0,
                            t: 20,
                            w: window.innerWidth,
                            h: window.innerHeight                            
                        };
                        return coordsWindow;
                    }, within: true
                }
            );                            
        } 
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Many thanks

Comment: Since I placed this in a module the defined constraints are not respected. I can move the pane out of the window. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In example #1 you are trying to use the `dojo/dnd/move` module as a parent of your class, whereas in example #2 you are not.

```
return declare("dashboardFloatingPane", [move, FloatingPane], {
```

vs

```
dojo.declare("dashboardFloatingPane", dojox.layout.FloatingPane, {
```

I don't believe the `dojo/dnd/move` module is not a valid class to be inheriting from, thus the error that it is not a callable constructor.

Comment: if you wish to extend you module with dojo/dnd/move you can call `dojo.mixin(this /* in ctor */, move);`